# Mac App Store Character Set error!

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac-appstore

I'm having trouble with the Mac App Store.
It shows me error messages with question marks instead of normal letters as in the following pic. 
[image: mac app store message]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What version of OS X are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Applications folder and start up the Font Book app and do File > Restore Standard Fonts and restart.

If that doesn't work, try a Safe Boot.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is font corruption at OS-level

Reinstall your current OS's latest combo updater - find it [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?q=combo%20update&src=globalnav_support&type=organic&page=search) & refine the search at top left for your actual current OS.